# Deterministically shuffling of array

Tags: c++, voxels, simplex-noise

I couldn't find an answer to this so I'm asking here, I've made a voxel engine and it's working reasonably well, except for a small detail: I have yet to figure out how to seed my simplex noise engine, the internet gave me two suggestions:

Generate simplex of one dimension higher with the fourth axis being the seed, this worked but was painfully slow in comparison.

Shuffle the permutation table, I like this idea. It should (if my understanding of math is correct) yield 512! permutations, however I don't know how to shuffle an array reliably in a deterministic manner, I want the shuffle to be the same every time I use the same seed.
so something like shuffle(perm, 12) would return the same every time the seed is 12 but something different when the seed is 22321.

So what I really wish to know is either how to shuffle the permutation table in a fast, reliable and deterministic manner using a seed or a better method for seeding simplex noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how I 've done it (c#)

```
        private static float[] grad = new float[256];
        private static int[] p = {151,160,137,91,90,15,
 131,13,201,95,96,53,194,233,7,225,140,36,103,30,69,142,8,99,37,240,21,10,23,
 190, 6,148,247,120,234,75,0,26,197,62,94,252,219,203,117,35,11,32,57,177,33,
 88,237,149,56,87,174,20,125,136,171,168, 68,175,74,165,71,134,139,48,27,166,
 77,146,158,231,83,111,229,122,60,211,133,230,220,105,92,41,55,46,245,40,244,
 102,143,54, 65,25,63,161, 1,216,80,73,209,76,132,187,208, 89,18,169,200,196,
 135,130,116,188,159,86,164,100,109,198,173,186, 3,64,52,217,226,250,124,123,
 5,202,38,147,118,126,255,82,85,212,207,206,59,227,47,16,58,17,182,189,28,42,
 223,183,170,213,119,248,152, 2,44,154,163, 70,221,153,101,155,167, 43,172,9,
 129,22,39,253, 19,98,108,110,79,113,224,232,178,185, 112,104,218,246,97,228,
 251,34,242,193,238,210,144,12,191,179,162,241, 81,51,145,235,249,14,239,107,
 49,192,214, 31,181,199,106,157,184, 84,204,176,115,121,50,45,127, 4,150,254,
 138,236,205,93,222,114,67,29,24,72,243,141,128,195,78,66,215,61,156,180};
```

when I change seed a redefine the the gradient array using the c# random class

```
    private static void InitPerlinPerm(uint seed)
    {
        Random r = new Random((int)seed);
        for (uint i = 0; i < grad.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            grad[i] = (r.Next(0, 32000) / 32000f);
        }
    }
```

here where I generate values:

```
    private float pseudoRandomFromPerm(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        return grad[(x + p[y + p[z & 255] & 255]) % grad.GetLength(0)];
    }
```

try this without regenerate the grad array or shuffering the p array:

```
    private float pseudoRandomFromPerm(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        return grad[(SEED + x + p[y + p[z & 255] & 255]) % grad.GetLength(0)];
    }
```

Comment: That's an interesting solution, however I don't think C++ has a native random function in its standard library that works this way, at least none of the ones I'm familiar with from the <random> header.

Comment: Another solution.: P[i] = P[i] + seed % 512  ;(foreach i) this if your perm array size is 512 and 512 seeds are enough (sorry typing from phone)

Comment: @CubeGod `srand(seed)` + `rand()` are the C / C++ equivalent.

Comment: srand(seed) and rand() to randomize, then a for loop to assign the shuffled numbers to a new array, if I understand the suggestion properly.
That could work, I've never really worked with srand or rand in years, last I used them was years ago because it was in a tutorial on random numbers (however it was terrible so I learned of <random> and have used that header ever since). I'll play around with this and see what sort of results I get.

Comment: Something very odd is happening, I opted for using the knuth shuffle while seeding srand with my seed (of type uint_least64_t because that's what my seed generator spits out), please see the edit of my original post for the oddness.

Comment: Nevermind, fixed the oddness. my permutation table is now shuffling properly (t'was a simple off by one error that I found when looking over my array copying code, I have a static constant perm array that I copy to the perm I use for generating noise, that way I have a sane starting point in case I need to generate more noise)

I would have edited but apparently 5 minutes is too long ago.